# Publish android library to s3

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am following [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library) tutorial to publish my library onto AWS S3 and use it in an independent project (not in a module of lirary root project). When My AWS Bucket name is for example `MY-SDK` and I have created two folders inside `snapshots` and `releases`. My library module name is `sdk` and project name is `ABC`. When I trigger the command `uploadArchive` it pushes

```
s3://MY-SDK/snapshots/ABC-sdk-android/sdk/unspecified/sdk-unspecified.aar

s3://MY-SDK/snapshots/ABC-sdk-android/sdk/unspecified/ivy-unspecified.xml
```

Am I missing something here or this is fine?

After this when I try to add this as a dependency to a different indipendent project it says cannot resolve

```
com.group_id:artifact_id:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Can somebody please point out what I am missing?

Comment: Did you add the credentials to your root build.gradle file? From the guide see **Adding the private Maven repository**.

Comment: yep I added the aws creds to both project gralde files

Comment: @JaredRummler can u verify if the folder structure in which gradle is uploading file onto s3 is fine?